# jQuery .submit() method sends undefined instead of written content after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm adding some content through form to the database and then reload this part of page to update the content. And then I want to add the next content and again reload but the .submit method I use, sends undefined instead of the written content. Here's the HTML code:

```
<form id="addForm" method="post" action="/addContent">
    <input type="text" id="content" name="name" value="" placeholder="New content" required/><br/><br/>

    <input name="submitted" id="submitted" value="Add content" class="submit" type="submit"  />
</form>
```

And here's JS:

```
<script>
$('#addForm').submit(function() {
    $.post('/addContent', {
        data: $('#addForm').serializeArray(),
    }, function(response) {
        $('#contentPart').html(response);
    });
        return false;
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me? I'll be gratefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your event on any `addForm` form that may appear in DOM in the future:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#addForm', function() {
...
});
```